# how to print string with spaces taken by user?

Tags: java

I am trying to concatenate 2 strings. I have already declared one string in the code and taking the other string as an user input. what changes do i need to make to inorder to print those concatenated strings.

**Following is something I tried:**

```
String s = "Java ";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter user string:");
String s2 = sc.nextLine(); //**user input taken:** is the best.

//**for concatenation**

s2=s+s2;
System.out.println(s2);
```

**Output**:

expected result:

> Java is the best.

actual result:

> Java is

Comment: Your code works just fine running from console.

Comment: Did you copy the second string for input? Scanner sc.nextLine() will break the line after getting a new line character in input

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs just fine from console, using Java 1.8.

However, reusing the same pointer both on the left side and right side of an equals-sign might introduce some weird behavior. I'm talking specifically of this line:

```
s2=s+s2;
```

`s2` is already a pointer in its own right, it points to an object allocated in memory. And you're trying to reassign this pointer at the same time as you access it. That being said, such issues is generally handled well in modern Java, so I'm unsure which version you are running and under which IDE if any.

But, notice that you don't need to do this at all. You could simply print what you want concatenated with `s2`:

`System.out.println("Java "+s2);`

No reassigning necessary, and no `s1` necessary.

Comment: I am running it in netbeans ide 8.2

Answer (score 0):

it would be, System.out.println(s + s2);

it would be smarter to initiate and declare a new variable instead of reusing s2. you could use s3 = s + s2;

Comment: I tried taking s3, but it's not reading my string "is the best".

Comment: it's only printing o/p as "Java is" when I am writing sc.next(). And when I do sc.nextLine(), it only prints "Java " and not user input string.

Answer (score 0):

**Tried this and it's executed:**

System.out.printf(s);

while(sc.hasNext()==true)

{

```
s2=sc.next();

System.out.printf(s2+" ");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility looks to me is, if your input has an end line character available in your input string. Are you keying in the input or using a copy paste for it? If yes, try to enter input by entering manually by keying each char.